# VF Test Class: Pass id to controller at start

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller

My visualforce page is opened via button on a custom object called Employee.

Here is the button code:
Behavior - Execute JavaScript

```
OnClick JavaScript  window.location = 'apex/EmpMerge?hbsId={!Employees__c.Id}&hbsName={!Employees__c.Name}';
```

How do similarly pass the ID of the employee in the test class to the controller?

```
@istest
public class test_empMergeController {}

@testSetup static void setupTestData(){
***Setup test data***
}

@isTest static void viewAsBCS() {
        User uBCS = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTBCS'];
        RecordType RecType = [Select Id from RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard EE Session - Acorn'];       

        //Query Employee
        Employees__c employee = [Select Id FROM Employees__c LIMIT 1];
        Employees__c employee2 = [Select Id FROM Employees__c WHERE ID != :employee.Id LIMIT 1];

        //Create Acorn Sessions and Benefits
        system.runAs(uBCS){
            //Create Session
            ***Code***

            //Elect Benefits
            ***Code***

            test.startTest();

            Test.setCurrentPage(Page.EmpMerge);
            //How do I pass employee.id to controller in test?
            //Page is called via button on custom object - Employees__c
            EmpMerge_Controller controller = new EmpMerge_Controller();

            test.stopTest();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following syntax in your test method to set the test page and then put params in current page.

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference( Page.PageName);
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('param', paramValue);
```

Once the page is set using first line,  you can add or change params as per your requirement using second line.

Answer (score 2):

You never need to call `Test.setCurrentPage`. It's the most useless function the platform offers. Simply do:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('parameter', 'value');
```

Comment: hmm -- if the underlying controller needs to inspect which page it is on (multi-page wizard use case perhaps), doesn't `Test.setCurrentPage(..)` help?

Comment: When would you ever need to know anything about the current page other than to retrieve its parameters? And when you do that, it doesn't matter *which* page you're on. Unless you are validating the current url, it seems rather beside the point. @crop

Comment: probably, I had always hoped that `Test.setCurrentPage()` would clear out the ApexPages.Messages generated to date so you could more easily code multiple error use cases in the same testmethod without having to resort to getting the last message added to the page to verify - but it doesn't do that last time I looked. Be nice if it also cleared the params too

Comment: @crop Hmm, that doesn't sound like **unit** testing, per se.